# Clean URLs not working on centos 6 vps

Tags: 7, .htaccess

I have installed drupal 7 in my vps running centos, but while i run clean url test using the drupal 7 clean url option in order to enable it the it shows error like this: "The clean URL test failed."
After diving into this problem i found that there is someting i should do in the `httpd.conf`, So i have added this to my httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then i have restarted my apache like so:

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

But still The clean URL test failed :/
Any idea? Thanks

**Edit:**

---

From MF82 Comment: The site located in `/var/www/my_domain_name.com/public_html`
I have also try this with no luck:

```
<Directory "/var/www/my_domain_name.com/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

---

From  Clive♦ Comment:
From the command i get this in my terminal:
[image]

Comment: Is your drupal install located in /var/www or is it in a subfolder of /var/www?

Comment: and `httpd -M | grep rewrite_module` shows that the rewrite module is installed and enabled?

Comment: @Clive, It will be mod_rewrite under CentOS.  You can check this at admin/reports/status/php.  The list of enabled Apache module is near the top of the page.

Comment: @MPD I checked the above on a cPanel install, result was `rewrite_module (static)`. I guess non cPanel CentOS builds refer to it differently?

Comment: @Clive I guess so.  I have >20 CentOS servers, both 5.x and 6.x, and all are mod_rewrite (eg, the loaded file is /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so).  But, I don't have any cPanel sites anymore.

Comment: Thankyou everyone :) @MF82 and Clive I have updatted my question. Thanks MPD the command mod_rewrite works in my system :)